# How to detect TapGesture in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am writing a container that has two buttons on corresponding borders which should be able to add inner lines inside the container. Previously the lines were being added one after another, but I want for the user to decide where to generate those lines. And the buttons on the borders cover the whole border so the logic is to let users tap on a border-button and the program should generate the line right at that location. I achieved it with DragGesture, but I want the users to tap the button not drag them and I am not able to figure out how can I replace the DragGesture here with TapGesture.

```
Button(action: {
                    addHorizontalLine()
                    self.selectedId = self.id //
                }) {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.clear)
                }
                .frame(width: 4, height: rectangleSize.height)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .position(x: 4 / 2, y: rectangleSize.height / 2)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                    .onEnded { value in
                        tappedPointY = value.location.y / rectangleSize.height
                        addHorizontalLine()
                            }
                        )
                .zIndex(1)

                Button(action: {
                    addVerticalLine()

                    self.selectedId = self.id //
                }) {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.clear)
                }
                .frame(width: rectangleSize.width, height: 4)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .position(x: rectangleSize.width / 2, y: 4 / 2)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                    .onEnded { value in
                        tappedPointX = value.location.x / rectangleSize.width
                        addVerticalLine()
                            }
                    )//
                .zIndex(1)
```

And here are the adding functions:

```
private func addHorizontalLine() {
        let y = rectangleSize.height * tappedPointY
        horizontalLines.append(y)
        horizontalLines = horizontalLines.sorted()
    }

    private func addVerticalLine() {
        let x = rectangleSize.width * tappedPointX
        verticalLines.append(x)
        verticalLines = verticalLines.sorted()
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the current tap location you can use the .onTapGesture functionality and create yourself a CGPoint from your tap like this..

```
    var body: some View {
      VStack {
        Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .onTapGesture { location in
            let tap = CGPoint(x: location.x, y: location.y)
            print("\(tap)")
        }
        .padding()
}
```

Edit:
Because it seemed that I was not clear enough I created a short programm with this drawing functionality.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    // you need two CGPoints to identify where the user clicked
    @State private var startTapLocation: CGPoint?
    @State private var endTapLocation: CGPoint?
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                //Background
                Color.white
                
                // draw line
                if let start = startTapLocation, let end = endTapLocation {
                    Path { path in
                        path.move(to: start)
                        path.addLine(to: end)
                    }
                    .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 2)
                }
            }
            //onTapGestures to identify the taps
            .onTapGesture {
                location in
                if startTapLocation == nil && endTapLocation == nil {
                    print("set startTapLocation, endTap is empty")
                    startTapLocation = CGPoint(x: location.x, y: location.y)
                } else
                if startTapLocation == nil && endTapLocation != nil {
                    startTapLocation = CGPoint(x: location.x, y: location.y)
                    endTapLocation = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
                    print("set startTapLocation, endTap is not empty")
                } else
                if (startTapLocation != nil && endTapLocation == nil) {
                    endTapLocation = CGPoint(x: location.x, y: location.y)
                    print("set endTapLocation")
                } else
                if (startTapLocation != nil && endTapLocation != nil){
                    startTapLocation = CGPoint(x: location.x, y: location.y)
                    print("set startTapLocation again")
                }
                
                print("Start tap: \(String(describing: startTapLocation)) , End Tap: \(String(describing: endTapLocation))")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You need to add this functionality to your existing View.

Comment: I tried this way but it doesn't add the lines inside the container when I do that, maybe I implemented them wrong I don't know

Comment: I added the whole functionality and tested the drawing mechanism. This works on my iPhone 14 simulator.
Tbh. the if/else - stuff could be improved if you like to.

greetings :)

Comment: If my solution was fine for your problem, it would be amazing to accept my answer. Thanks and have a good weekend

Comment: I will try to implement this now, thank you